# PHP API access - continue after oauth2 authentication

Tags: php, api, dropbox

This is rather a basic question. I'm just getting started with using API calls. I'm trying to use the Dropbox API.

My app has the following code:

```
<?php
require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app-info.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "CharmsBox/1.0");
$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();
print "<p>Authorize the App <a href=\"".$authorizeUrl."\">now</a></p>";
print '
<p class="ui-widget">Auth Key: <input id="authkey">
<a id="btnAuth" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#" tabindex="2">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash" aria-hidden="true"></span>Authenticate
</a>                              
</p>';  
?>
```

In another tab, I enter the username and password to authenticate. Dropbox gives the auth code. I'm now supposed to use this code to generate user id and access token as below:

```
list($accessToken, $userId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
echo "Authorization complete.\n";
echo "- User ID: $userId\n";
echo "- Access Token: $accessToken\n";
```

However since my php code has already finished execution, I'm unable to run the above code. I tried using the following in another php script, and using GET request:

```
require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app-info.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "CharmsBox/1.0");
if (isset($_GET['authcode'])) {  
    list($accessToken, $userId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
    echo "Authorization complete.\n";
    echo "- User ID: $userId\n";
    echo "- Access Token: $accessToken\n";
    return;
} else {
  print "Unauthenticated call of script!";
  return;
}
```

However that gives me the following error code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ''code' must not be null' in /var/www/virtual/mydomain/split/htdocs/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/Checker.php
```

The original example script at Dropbox looks like this:

```
echo "1. Go to: $authorizeUrl\n";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).\n";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code.\n";
echo "Enter the authorization code here: ";
$authCode = \trim(\fgets(STDIN));
list($accessToken, $userId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
echo "Authorization complete.\n";
echo "- User ID: $userId\n";
echo "- Access Token: $accessToken\n";
```

How can I continue with authentication with the generated accesscode? Specifically, how can I accept a web based input instead of STDIN and continue authentication?

Answer (score 0):

In a web app, you probably want to use `dbx\WebAuth`, rather than `dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect`. Check out the [web file browser example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/master/examples/web-file-browser.php) in the SDK.